# PHP / AJAX Contact Form - Page Opens Mid-Way

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So I've been using this contact form on my website, and it works great. However, the page opens up mid-way at the "Services" tab rather than at the top of the page as usual. I'm new to PHP so I really have no idea how to fix it. No one else seems to have this similar problem, so I haven't been able to find a solution on google.

Here is the website: http://katyasarmiento.zzl.org

And here is the PHP on the home page (index.php):

```
<hr id="Contact">
  <p class="spechead">Contact<small>alovely<a href="http://about.me/katyasarmiento">lady</a></small></p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> &nbsp;<span class="specbody">katwebd@gmail.com</span></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> &nbsp;<span class="specbody">305.890.9834</span></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> &nbsp;<span class="specbody"><a href="http://www.doodle.com/katwebdesigns">Schedule</a> a free consultation</span></div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <p class="specbody"> DO NOT TRY THE CONTACT FORM, I AM STILL WORKING ON IT. THANK YOU!</p>
  <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">
    <p class="specbody">Fill out the contact form below to get in touch with me! Please provide as much information as possible so I can help you with your enquiry :)</p>
      <?php
      //init variables
      $cf = array();
      $sr = false;

      if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
        $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
        $sr = true;
      }
            ?>
            <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
                <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
                <?php 
        if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
          foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
        ?>
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
                <?php
          endforeach;
        endif;
        ?>
            </ul>
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks for your message! I will get back to you ASAP!</p>
            <form method="post" action="process.php">
                <label for="name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus />

                <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="email@example.com" required />

                <label for="telephone">Telephone: </label>
                <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['telephone'] : '' ?>" />

                <label for="enquiry">Enquiry: </label>
                <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">
                    <option value="General" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'General') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>General - Say Hello!</option>
                    <option value="Sales" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Sales') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Sales - Services & Pricing</option>
                    <option value="Support" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['enquiry'] == 'Support') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Support - Current Clients</option>
                </select>

                <label for="message">Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 charcters" required data-minlength="20"><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>

                <span id="loading"></span>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit-button" />
                <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>
            </form>
          <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
      </div> <!-- form -->
```

And here's the php on a separate file called "process.php", but I don't think that's the problem.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST) ){

//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');

//form data
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//validate form data

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($name)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}

//validate message is not empty
if(empty($message)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
}
//validate message is greater than 20 charcters
elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
}

//send email if all is ok
if($formok){
    $headers = "From: Katya@katyasarmiento.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the enquiries form on your website.</p>
                  <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                  <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                  <p><strong>Telephone: </strong> {$telephone} </p>
                  <p><strong>Enquiry: </strong> {$enquiry} </p>
                  <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                  <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

    mail("KatWebD@gmail.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);

}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'telephone' => $telephone,
        'enquiry' => $enquiry,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors
);


//if this is not an ajax request
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
    //set session variables
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

    //redirect back to form
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
```

Like I said, the form works fine. It sends the emails and such. I just don't like how the page opens right above the contact form.

Comment: Have you got a #services in you url??

Comment: @Gavin no I do not. When you click on Services, it DOES take you to #services tab, but otherwise the URL is not supposed to open at #services.
When I take out the contact form, the page opens up at the top, so I know it's not an HTML problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first input in the contact form has autofocus. This is causing the browser to scoll down to the form in order to, well, ahem, autofocus it.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is being loaded twice. the second jquery have been loading, the page goes to the service tab, because for all events is triggered two times.

You should call the same scripts 1 time

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I must be reading over it because I can't find it in my code.

Comment: your index file

loading jquery
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

loading bootstrsap
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

and loading bootstrap secondly (now that will be triggered by events in the file 2 times)
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

...
events will be triggered twice now in jquery
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

You should call the same scripts 1 time

Comment: Oh okay, yeah I see what you mean. But taking out the double scripts doesn't fix the problem. If I take out the php code of the contact form on the index.php completely, it fixes the problem so it must be something in that code.

Comment: i understood. the id attribute must be unique, but the "contact-form", which is more than one. so the page goes in this section.

Another reason may be because of the unclosed html tag. one strong tag and two < div class = "container" > unclosed.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed all of these mistakes, but it's still not fixing the problem with the php. I changed the ID to "contactform" and closed the tags. The page still loads at "Services" and the only fix is to delete the php code on the page. I want to know what is wrong with the php code that's making the page load right above the contact form.